# Elementos aleatorios de un array

Tags: php, array

Tengo problemas con este código que trato de ejecutar:

```
$buscar = array("necesito 01","necesito 02","necesito 03");

$resul = $buscar[mt_rand(0, count($buscar) - 1)];
    $query = array(
        "q" => "'+$resul+'",
            "count" => 4,
            "result_type" => "recent",  
    );
```

No me da el resultado deseado lo que necesito es que la variable **$resul**  que esta dentro del **array** sea aleatoria pero me da error.

Comment: Tras la edición, creo que he dejado de entender el propósito. Necesitas tomar un elemento aleatorio del array `$buscar` ??

Comment: @Muriano Lo que no logro es meter el resultado de `$resul` dentro del `array("");` da error de la manera en que esta el el código

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, debería servirte para incluir el texto generado. Necesitas las comillas simples y los símbolos + ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php), pero en la práctica es una función más lenta y menos aleatoria que el código siguiente:

```
<?php

    $buscar = array("necesito 01","necesito 02","necesito 03");

    $result = $buscar[mt_rand(0, count($buscar) - 1)];

    $query = array(
        // "q" => "'+" . $result. "+'", // Concatenación
        "q" => "'+{$result}+'", // Magic Quotes
        "count" => 4,
        "result_type" => "recent",  
    );
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta recién actualice el código para ser mas claro con la pregunta

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions He editado con dos opciones para añadir el elemento seleccionado a tu array de resultados.

Comment: @Mariano Gracias por la respuesta funciona muy bien .

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien que tu problema es recoger `$result` en el array para la consulta, prueba:

```
$query = array(
        "q" => $result,
            "count" => 4,
            "result_type" => "recent",  
);
```

sería la forma correcta de llamar a la variable.

Comment: Esto no resuelve el problema completo. Fíjate además que en el primer caso, estás usando el operador de concatenación `.`, sin embargo todo el código está dentro de una misma cadena delimitada por comillas simples `'`, que son más estrictas en su uso y la cadena no tomará el valor de la variable `$resul`

Comment: Tenías razón con la primera opción Muriano, he editado, pero el problema queda resuelto ya que es cómo asigna el valor de $result a "q".